# How to access the Kubernetes external IP as HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes

I've deployed a Django app on Azure Kubernetes service using a load balancer service. So far accessing the external IP of the load balancer I'm able to access my application but I need to expose the app for HTTPS requests. 
I'm new to Kubernetes and unable to find any article which provides these steps. So please help me with the steps/action I need to perform to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expose your application using ingress.Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls)  on how to do it in azure kubernetes service.

Comment: Agreed that the ingress is the correct choice. You also have the option of securing your application with SSL at the container level and if you expose the service as a load balancer and use the external IP to connect, you will be able to access your application over HTTPS. This is also true for using `NodePort`.

Comment: Yes that's another option..is there a guide for azure kubernetes service?